# Atomicity in distributed tensorflow when updating variables

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I'm working on distributed tensorflow. However I have curious things about updating the variables.

Suppose we tried to train the model with Parameter Server system with 1 PS and N workers.

When they are updating variables one worker by worker, is there any guarantees of atomicity during updating variables?

Specifically, can I check the source codes in TensorFlow where the atomicity of variables are provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the Variable has an `assign_add` interface, this interface has an argument: `use_locking`(False by default). Thus I think there are no guarantees of atomicity during updating variables if you do not set `use_locking`.

Comment: Thanks for reply my question. Then it means that if ‘use_locking’ is false, there is no guarantee to atomicity of variables when several workers try to update variables in distributed training, right??